# Не понял суть задания

Tags: c, график

**Дано вещественное число a. Для функции  , график которой приведён ниже, вычислить**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
        int x, y;
        printf("Введите x");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(-3 > x){
            y = 2;
        }
        if(-3 < x && x < 2){
            y = 4;
        }
        if(2 < x){
            y = 1;
        }
        printf("%d", y);
        return 0;
    }
```

Вот все что я сделал, попытался понять, но мне что-то подсказывает, что это не правильно.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1419790/2739

Comment: ну да, только суть задания я так и не понял

Comment: код почти правильный. подумайте, какой будет вывод при x = 2 и -3. Да, можно в 2 if решить, а можно и в три. Суть задания - написать код, который будет вычислять функцию. всех делов то

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо написать программу, которая по заданному значению аргумента функции  вычисляет значение функции.

Смотрим на график.

По графику при x <= -3 (именно меньше *или равно* — видите кружок?) функция принимает значение 3.

*Иначе* при x <= 2 функция принимает значение 4. *Во всех остальных случаях* она равна 1.

Т.е. функция имеет вид

```
double F(double x)
{
    if (x <= -3) return 3;
    else if (x <= 2) return 4;
    else return 1;
}
```

Вот и все. Осталось встроить ее в программу.

```
int main()
{
    double x;
    printf("Input x: ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("F(%lf) = %lf\n",x,F(x));
}
```

Всё. В целом у вас сделано практически то же самое, только нет необходимых *или равно*, и значение аргумента только целочисленное, в то время как функция вполне определена, например, для числа 3.1415926...

Comment: `именно меньше или равно — видите кружок?` Разве «выколотую точку» используют не для того, чтобы исключить точку из некоторого множества?

Comment: @wololo Как бы выразиться... Когда я учился, это было так, как я написал. Сейчас — даже не знаю... Может, за 40 лет и подзабыл все эти обозначения :)